# CMake: Why doesn't POST_BUILD in add_custom_command(...) work?

Tags: makefile, cmake

I have some trouble when I use `PRE_BUILD` | `PRE_LINK` | `POST_BUILD` in command `add_custom_command(...)`. When I use `POST_BUILD`, I found the command will execute before the target has been built, like this:

```
[root@VM_33_35_centos build]# make 
Scanning dependencies of target main 
[100%] Building C object CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.c.o 
Linking C executable main 
This is pre build 
This is post build 
[100%] Built target main
```

The contents of my `CMakeLists.txt` are:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8) 
add_executable(main main.c) 
add_custom_command(TARGET main 
                     PRE_BUILD 
                    COMMAND echo "This is pre build " 
        ) 
add_custom_command(TARGET main 
                    POST_BUILD 
                   COMMAND echo "This is post build" 
        )
```

Why did the command `echo "This is post build"` on line 8 of `CMakeLists.txt` not execute after the `[100%] Built target main` message on line 7(Linux command)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command added with `add_custom_command(TARGET)` signature becomes **part of the target**, that is target can be assumed to be built (`Built target main`) only *after given command is executed*.

Description of `POST_BUILD` keyword

> run after the target has been built

means that command is executed after **target file** (in your case executable `main`) is created. This file is created as part of linking process, started after line `Linking C executable main`.